# Entity Framework 6 get the sql from code first migration

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to get the sql of some migrations that were already executed on my developer machine, so I can execute them on some other enviroment(qa, prod, ...).
I found this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx (section **Getting a SQL Script**), but this works only if you have pending migrations. I tried:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase -TargetMigration: SomeMigration
```

but got `Target database is already at version SomeMigration.`

Can I get the sql of already executed migration?

EF6, MVC5, VisualStudio 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it does exactly what it should since you invoke `Update-Database` on your local environment.

If you need to generate update script for another environment I see the following options:

- You can **target your local application to the database from remote environment**. In this case it is enough to change connection string in your `web.config` manually.
- You can **revert your local database to the state of the database that your remote environment is targeting**. 
  `Update-Database –TargetMigration: "last migration on remote environment"`